# File not found when assets used as linked content

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I am trying to use images in an assets directory located below the project root. My directory structure is like this

- Solution Root

  - Project Root
  - Assets Directory

My .csproj file is set up with the following lines

```
<Content Include="..\Assets\*.png">
  <Link>Assets\%(FileName)</Link>
</Content>
```

This shows the assets folder and assets png files in the project in Visual Studio as if they were in the project folder.

My XAML is including the assets like this

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/myimage.png"/>
```

but every single image is not appearing. Everything worked until I tried to move the assets directory and now even though the project appears identical the images are missing. Does anyone know the correct way to fix this problem?

Comment: try `<Content Include="~\Assets\*.png">` instead of `<Content Include="..\Assets\*.png">`

Comment: Doesn't find the images to add them to the project if I do that

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete source URI, including your assembly-name:

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///My.Assembly/Assets/myimage.png"/>
```